# How to add angular to django 1.6 temlate

Tags: angularjs, django, angularjs-1.6

I have such template in django:

```
<!DOCTYPE html > 
<html ng-app>
<head>
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "style.css" %}" />
 <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p> red </p>

<input type="text" ng-model="name">
<h2> Hello {{ name }} </h2>
</body> 
</html>
```

But when i write some name in input, the name dont appear near "hello"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the {{ }} notation is also used by the template engine of Django. You have to use the tags openvariable and closevariable such as :

```
<h2> Hello {% templatetag openvariable %} name {% templatetag closevariable %} </h2>
```

So when it gets rendered, the actual {{ and }} are seen by angular.

The angular script may not be loaded with :

```
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
```

try adding http://

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: I try but i have mistake Invalid block tag: 'openvariable'

Comment: I copy from your answer but nothing, in template when its render this Hello {{ name }}

Comment: I edited the answer as I tried your exact sample code